# Expresso Store Fatal Error: FakePDO not found

Tags: expresso-store

Just attempted to install Expresso Store and I get the following warning and error and I am unable to proceed:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Class 'Store\Illuminate\FakePDO' not found
>
> Filename: store/autoload.php
>
> Line Number: 50

and

> ...expressionengine/third_party/store/vendor/expressodev/laravel-codeigniter-db/src/Illuminate/CodeIgniter/CodeIgniterConnectionResolver.php
>   on line 24

I am running EE 2.8.1.

Comment: Does the "store/autoload.php" file exist in your install?

Comment: Yes it does exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue running Store on some servers (where PDO is not installed), and is fixed in the upcoming version.

In the meantime, you can open up `third_party/store/autoload.php`, and around line 50, change this line:

```
class_alias('Store\Illuminate\FakePDO', 'PDO');
```

to this:

```
class_alias('Illuminate\CodeIgniter\FakePDO', 'PDO');
```

Comment: Hi Adrian, I was able to get PDO installed on the server, so everything is working now. This is good to know though and I appreciate your help.